# How do I play multiple songs stored in my raw folder using MediaPlayer in android?

Tags: android, media-player, mediacontroller

How do I play multiple songs that I have stored in a raw folder using MediaPlayer using seek and previous? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To play a file from your Android project's raw folder:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(yourActivity, R.raw.filename);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

If you have multiple files and want to use next/previous, just create an ArrayList< Object > with your files and write something to select the files from that list.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that